# Microsoft SQL. I need to group by day from 03:00 until 03:00

Tags: sql-server

I am facing problem while writing sql query. The scenario is that we have 5 Shifts of work in a day. 
Fifth shift starts at Monday 22:00 and closed at Tuesday 02:30.
How could I include all the data for shift 5 into Monday's date?

```
SELECT    CONVERT(date,t_stamp) AS 'Date',
          COUNT(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Count',
          SUM(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Volume'
FROM      TT1_table
GROUP BY  CONVERT(date,t_stamp)
Order By 'Date'
```

```
t_stamp,tt1_table_ndx,TT1_Classed_Height,TT1_Classed_Length,TT1_Classed_Volume,TT1_Classed_Width,TT1_Plank_Name
2019-12-09 16:24:30.407 839402  25  5400    0,01539 114 251145400
2019-12-09 16:24:26.507 839401  38  6600    0,0381216   152 381526600
2019-12-09 16:24:23.870 839400  38  6600    0,0381216   152 381526600
2019-12-09 16:24:14.943 839399  38  6600    0,0381216   152 381526600
2019-12-09 16:23:53.043 839398  38  6000    0,034656    152 381526000
2019-12-09 16:23:46.627 839397  25  5400    0,01026 76  250765400
2019-12-09 16:23:33.787 839396  38  6000    0,017328    76  380766000
2019-12-09 16:23:27.377 839395  38  6600    0,0381216   152 381526600
2019-12-09 16:23:24.740 839394  25  6600    0,01881 114 251146600
2019-12-09 16:23:18.327 839393  38  6600    0,0381216   152 381526600
```

Comment: You can subtract a few hours from Tuesday records before doing your calculus. Or even better define your shifts in a physical table then join with a `between` and group by the shift. Either way, it would be great if you could supply your table's structure, sample data and wanted outcome.

Comment: Substract 2.5 hours, so the first 2:30 hours will be accounted on a shift of the previous day : dateadd(hour, 2.5, t_stamp)

Comment: Thank you. CONVERT(date,dateadd(hour, -3, t_stamp)) Worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the hour selection you can do

```
     SELECT    DATEPART(HOUR, t_stamp) AS 'Date',
      COUNT(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Count',
      SUM(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Volume'
     FROM      TT1_table
     where DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())=18
      GROUP BY  DATEPART(HOUR, t_stamp)
     Order By 'Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post sample data to assist better. I am assuming your datetime columns will be in 24-hour time format. Please try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())  -- will give you the current hour.


SELECT    CONVERT(date,t_stamp) AS 'Date',
          COUNT(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Count',
          SUM(TT1_Classed_Volume) AS 'Volume'
FROM      TT1_table
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, shift_begin_time_stamp) >= 22 and DATEPART(HOUR, shift_end_time_stamp) <= 5
GROUP BY  t_stamp
Order By 'Date'
```